# Como desabilitar algumas teclas C#?

Tags: c#, teclado

Gostaria de saber como faço para desabilitar/bloquear algumas teclas do teclado enquanto o programa estiver em execução ou até o cancelamento do bloqueio?

Por exemplo: Se eu desabilitar/bloquear todo o teclado ou apenas permitir x tecla não seria possível usá-la em qualquer outro programa até fechar o programa ou cancelar o bloqueio das teclas.

Tem como ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Boa tarde, Você necessita fazer este bloqueio em uma aplicação windows form ou web?

Comment: Você necessita fazer este bloqueio em uma aplicação windows form ou web?

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste artigo. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resposta caso for uma aplicação Desktop, no caso de aplicação Web, não conheço solução.

Primeiramente, isso não é algo legal de se fazer, caso tenha algum antivírus ou algo assim será detectado seu aplicativo como virus, até porque muitos keyloggers utilizam a mesma técnica.

Para isso será necessário efetuar alguns hooks de baixo nivel no sistema.
Existem muitas maneiras de fazer isso, você pode fazer 'na mão', ou utilizar alguns frameworks.

No exemplo abaixo irei fazer a partir de um framework que esta [nessa resposta aqui.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493540/disabling-windows-key-in-a-c-sharp-windows-form-app)

Github [Framework GlobalMouseKeyHook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook)

```
nuget install MouseKeyHook
```

O meu código no Windows Forms fica assim:

```
private IKeyboardMouseEvents m_GlobalHook;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_GlobalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();    //inicia instancia do hook        
    m_GlobalHook.KeyDown += MetodoKeyPressHook; //cria um hook para o metodo
}

private void MetodoKeyPressHook(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //apenas para o botao espaço:
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        e.Handled = true;

    //ou simplesmente para todas as teclas:
    e.Handled = true;

    //exemplo abaixo ele deixa normal as teclas e não ignora.
    e.Handled = false;
}
```

PS: cuidado na hora de debugar :D.

Comment: Bem, funcionou e não funcionou no programa que queria. Mas foi quase.

Comment: Era só executar como administrador, agora funfo :D, obrigado a todos.